# Laravel eloquent select data

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

**I want to build a eloquent query** which builds this output :

```
SELECT * FROM `banners` WHERE (`channel` = "en-us" OR `channel` IS NULL) AND (`language` = "en" OR `language`IS NULL) AND (`country` = 'us' OR `country` IS NULL) AND `category_id` = "3954" AND `valid_from` <= "2018-10-03 13:20:52" AND `valid_to` >= "2018-10-03 13:20:52" OR `valid_to` IS NULL
```

*I struggle with the "or" and "and" conditions.*

This should mean valid_from, valid_to, channel, language must have values, but in some cases "channel" and "language" can be null.

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses at the Parameter Grouping section.

Comment: Please also include the solution you have tried when you question. Have you tried the link I provided above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume that your eloquent model is `Banner`

```
public function valid_banner() {
        $data = $this
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query
                    ->where('valid_from', '<=', '2018-10-03 13:20:52')
                    ->where('valid_to', '>=', '2018-10-03 13:20:52')
                    ->where('channel', 'en-us')
                    ->where('language', 'en');
            })
            ->orWhere(fucntion($query) {
                $query
                    ->where(function($q) {
                        $q
                            ->where('valid_from', '<=', '2018-10-03 13:20:52')
                            ->whereNull('valid_to');
                    })
                    // i think you can use this (choose one of below)
                    ->orWhereNull('channel')
                    // use this if orWhereNull is not exists
                    ->orWhereRaw("channel IS NULL")

                    // i think you can use this (choose one of below)
                    ->orWhereNull('language')
                    // use this if orWhereNull is not exists
                    ->orWhereRaw("language IS NULL");
            })
            ->where('category_id', 3954)
            // you can skip this condition if you using SoftDeletes
            // read this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#soft-deleting
            ->whereNull($this->getTable(). '.deleted_at')

        ;

        return $data;
}
```

not tested yet. but hopefully you can get the point.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact output of your posted query, because I see some syntax errors in closing brackets of the query. so I can't completely understand your query.

But since you have pointed out that you are struggling with understanding how to use `and` and `or` in `query builder` I thought this might help.

```
DB::table('banners')
    ->where([                                         //     -|
        ['valid_from', '<=', '2018-10-03 13:20:52'],  // AND  |
        ['valid_to', '>=', '2018-10-03 13:20:52'],    // AND  |
        ['channel', 'en-us'],                         // AND  | OR
        ['language', 'en']                            // AND  |
    ])->orWhere([                                     //     _|____
        ['valid_from', '<=', '2018-10-03 13:20:52'],  // AND  | OR
        ['valid_to', null]                            // AND _|____
    ])->orWhereNull('channel')                        //     _| OR
    ->orWhereNull('language')                         //     _| OR
    ->get();
```

Best of luck